# Tomcat error 'The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.'

Tags: maven, tomcat, web-applications, error-handling

I am creating a webapp and I get the error while trying to run "http://localhost:8080/"

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message Not found

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for 
the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.20
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1"
 >

<!-- Invoke 'Generate' action to add tags or functions -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>searchServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.incidents.cashout.CurlExecutor</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>searchServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>getInputs.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B2ma.png)

I tried using other solutions but none of them seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your index.jsp directly under webapp folder.